# 2D Fourier transform of a table - ArrayPlot issue

Tags: plotting, fourier-analysis, list-manipulation

Recently, I have encountered an issue with ArrayPlot after performing a Fourier transform of a table.

[image: ArrayPlot of a 2D table with precalculated values]

Picture presented above is an ArrayPlot of a 2D table. Using Fourier on this 2D table I obtain the following ArrayPlot:

[image: Fourier transform of the first image.]

After this procedure one ends up with the result which consists of data at four vertices of the square. The thing is that I would like the result to be in this form:

[image]

I have tried different Fourier transform parameters but none of them had delivered the demanded image.

Thank you in advance for your reply!

Comment: I guess what you're looking for is an analogue of Matlab's [`fftshift`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html). It's not really an issue with `ArrayPlot`, it's an question of visualizing the result of the Fourier transform.

Answer (score 4):

This is really ancient code that should do what you need.
It was written on MMA version 3 or 4 (or 5??) - I don't remember - and I have not tested it on newer versions. 
If it does not work you'll probably have to find a newer procedure to extract the dimensions from an image.

So, here's the code, it works on a matrix of values and gives you a matrix that represents the (generally complex) FFT you are after:

> ```
> FFT2D[mat_] := Module[{ft, hshift, wshift},
>     ft = Fourier[mat];
>     {hshift, wshift} = IntegerPart[(# + .5)/2] & /@ Dimensions[ft];
>     Transpose[RotateLeft[
>         Transpose[RotateLeft[
>             ft,
>             hshift]],
>         wshift]]
> ]
> ```

This is how I used it back then (again, you might have to adjust the code, possibly by changing `ListDensityPlot` with `ArrayPlot`)

```
mat = GrayScaleMatrix["Image1.bmp"];
(* this was a silly conversion from color to grayscale, see later *)
{hshift, wshift} = IntegerPart[(# + .5)/2] & /@ Dimensions[mat]
(* this is just extracting the dimensions of the image*)
ListDensityPlot[mat, MeshRange -> {{-wshift, wshift}, {-hshift, hshift}}]
(* and this is plotting it to show the gray scaled image *)
```

Instead of `Fourier`, I would use `FFT2D`. That's it.

```
fft = FFT2D[mat];
```

Plotting might require the previously extracted information about the image's dimensions.

```
ListDensityPlot[Abs[fft], MeshRange -> {{-wshift, wshift}, {-hshift, hshift}}]
```

Addendum - And this is the procedure I used to convert color bitmaps into gray scale ones (I wanted to experiment with actual pictures and I did not have the time to figure out how to properly create a gray scaled version). I include it here just in case you want to try with the actual data it has worked for me

```
GrayScaleMatrix[filename_String] := Module[{pic},
    pic = Import[filename];
    pic[[1, 1]] /. {r_, g_, b_} :> (.3r + .6g + .1b)
    ]
```

Comment: `RotateLeft` can rotate rows and columns in one go: `RotateLeft[ft, {hshift, wshift}]`

Answer (score 2):

You schould always share some code :)

```
pic = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1IuJ.png"]
dat = ImageData@ColorConvert[pic, "GrayScale"];
Dimensions@dat

(img = ArrayPad[
        Abs[Fourier[dat]][[2 ;; 154, 2 ;; 154]],
       {{153, 0}, {153, 0}},
       "Reversed"]) // Image // ImageCrop // ColorNegate
```

> [image]

```
img // Image // ImageCrop[#, {60, 30}] & // ColorNegate
% // ImageAdjust
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: @Matt so, is this what you are after?